# Further question about a property of algebraic sets, specifically in direction of $V(\bigcup_{\alpha} S_{\alpha})=\bigcap_{\alpha}V(S_{\alpha})$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I would like some help in understanding the proof of the theorem enclosed below. Specifically it has to do with one of the direction in the proof

The definitions, theorem, proof and notations is from Knapp's Advanced Algebra text.
The more detailed proof in one direction is from the course [MA40188 Algebraic Curves.](https://ziyuzhang.github.io/ma40188/#Lectures_and_Office_Hours) Specifically [the solutions from first exercise sheet:](https://ziyuzhang.github.io/ma40188/Solution01.pdf)

The notations and definitions are as follow:
Let $k$ denote an algebraically closed field.  Fix a positing integer $n$ and denote by $A$ the polynomial ring $A=k[X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}].$  Typically ideals of $A$ will be denoted by $a,b,\ldots.$  We call the set $\mathbb{A}^{n}=\{(x_{1},\ldots x_{n})\in k^{n}\}$ an affine $n$-space.  Members of points in affine $n$-space, and the function $P\mapsto x_{j}(P)$ gives the coordinates of the points.

To each subset $S$ of polynomials in $A$, associate the locus of common zeros, or zero locus of the members of $S:$

$V(S)=\{P\in \mathbb{A}^{n}| f(P)=0 \text{ for all } f\in S\}$

$V(S)$ is called an affine algebraic set in $\mathbb{A}^{n}$.  If $S$ is a finite set $\{f_{1},\dots,f_{n}\}$ of polynomials, then $V(\{f_{1},\dots,f_{n}\})$ is abbreviated as $V(f_{1},\dots,f_{n}).$ From the definition that $V(S)=\bigcap_{f\in S} V(f)$ for any subset $S$ of $A$.

Theorem:  Affine algebraic sets in $\mathbb{A}^{n}$ have the following properties:

$V(\bigcup_{\alpha} S_{\alpha})=\bigcap_{\alpha}V(S_{\alpha})$ if the $S_{\alpha}$'s are arbitrary subsets of $A$.

Proof:

$V(\bigcup_{\alpha} S_{\alpha})=\bigcap_{f\in {\bigcup_{\alpha}S_{\alpha}}}V(f)=\bigcap_{\alpha}\bigcap_{f\in S_{\alpha}}V(f)=\bigcap_{\alpha}V(S_{\alpha})$.

I am trying to unpack one of the direction, namely $V(\bigcup_{\alpha} S_{\alpha})\subset \bigcap_{\alpha}V(S_{\alpha})$

So suppose $P\in V(\bigcup_{\alpha} S_{\alpha})$, then $f(P)=0$ for every $f\in \bigcup_{\alpha} S_{\alpha}.$  Here is where I am having difficulty.  In $f\in \bigcup_\alpha S_\alpha$ translates to there exists at least one $\alpha$ and $f\in S_{\alpha}$ or equivalently $\exists\alpha\wedge f\in S_{\alpha}$.  However sine there is an universal quantifier preceding $f$. does it mean something like the following: $\exists\alpha \wedge \forall f\in S_{\alpha}$. Also when I see "for every $f\in \bigcup_{\alpha} S_{\alpha}.$".  In plain english, does it mean, in all the $\alpha$s that are being refer to, $P\in S_{\alpha}$. In the end i still need to get to $\forall\alpha$, $P\in V(S_{\alpha})$.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $p \in V \left ( \bigcup_{\alpha} S_{\alpha} \right )$. Then $p$ is a zero of $f$ for all $f \in \bigcup_{\alpha} S_{\alpha}$, hence is in $V(S_{\alpha})$ for all $\alpha$. So $p \in \bigcap_{\alpha} V(S_{\alpha})$. Since $p$  was an arbitrary element of $V \left ( \bigcup_{\alpha} S_{\alpha} \right )$, $V \left ( \bigcup_{\alpha} S_{\alpha} \right ) \subset \bigcap_{\alpha} V(S_{\alpha})$.

Comment: I just want to make sure, "for all $f \in \bigcup_{\alpha} S_{\alpha}$", means $p$ is in $V(S_{\alpha})$ for all $\alpha$." Is that correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct